# How to get url Param in React

Tags: reactjs, redirect, post, routes

The spring_page has **human_number** and this data will be react_pages based need data
so I want to send human_number to react_page

```
<spring_page>       <react_page>
localhost:8080  ==> localhost:3000
```

Now I'm doing this by sending data directly using url
In spring_page -> call localhost:3000/human_number
and the react use  get human_number param

So The data is too clearly stated. I want to hide human_number Like POST_method [post_param]
I'm very new to REACT so It can be really silly question or I'm Approaching the wrong way
How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using react-router-dom you can pass url  params and you can also access the params from your own component.you have to give the colon(:) and then your id

```js
  <Route path={`${path}/:topicId`} component={Demo} />


 const Demo =({match}) => {
 console.log(match.params.id)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first component, you can trigger this onCick of a link or button

```
browserHistory.push({
    pathname: `/about`,
    search : 'param_here'
    state: {
        type: 'type'
    }
});
```

In your other component, you can now grab them like:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        search: props.location.search,
        type: props.location.state.type
    }
}
```